# Uncaught ReferenceError : connection is not defined

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

After upgrading my cordova from **3.1** to **3.4**, the cordova API became not working and through uncaught ReferenceError for API variables.

*Error Message:*

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Connection is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html

*Code:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>navigator.connection.type Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        checkConnection();
    }

        function checkConnection() {
        alert("on check connection");
            var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

            var states = {};
            states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
            states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
            states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

            alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
        }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>A dialog box will report the network state.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did u update the plugin as well ?

Comment: @DiveshSalian Yes, I recreated every thing. note that my android version is 4.4.2

Comment: @Moussawi7 had same issue.. did you solve this problem?

Comment: first, put your al function in controller file not in html. Connection object also not working in my code. same issue, i also tried to update cordova and check again..